# How to add spaces between xml elements xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have an XML as shown below and I am generating PDF using XSL FO XSLT transforamtion. How to add spaces between XML elements while dsiplaying them as table columns in the PDF?

```
<Reports>
<Report>
<BatchDate>2016-08-10T00:00:00</BatchDate>
<ClientAccountNo>ABCDE01384</ClientAccountNo>
<Source>N</Source>
<CDSNo>0000001387</CDSNo>
<Price>0.123000</Price>
<Qty>-1200</Qty>
<TCurrency>USD</TCurrency>
<TNettAmt>0</TNettAmt>
<LCurrency>USD</LCurrency>
<LNettAmt>-86.600000</LNettAmt>
<PromotionInd>N</PromotionInd>
<BrkChgID>BRK-N</BrkChgID>
<BrkChgAmt>50.000000</BrkChgAmt>
<ClrChgID>CLR</ClrChgID>
<ClrChgAmt>10.000000</ClrChgAmt>
<SdcChgID>SDC</SdcChgID>
<SdcChgAmt>1.000000</SdcChgAmt>
<BinChgID />
<BinChgAmt>0</BinChgAmt>
<OthChgAmt>0.000000</OthChgAmt>
<TaxAmt>0.000000</TaxAmt>
</Report>
</Reports>
```

While ouputting the above XML, I need to add a space between the XML elements like for instance, let us take TaxAmt, I need to output it as Tax Amt. How can i do this? Below is my XSLT

```
    <fo:table role="html:table" table-layout="auto" inline-progression-dimension="auto" line-height="2.5" width="100%" border="0px" border-collapse="collapse" border-spacing="3px" border-style="outset hidden" space-before.conditionality="retain" space-after.conditionality="retain" space-after="1em" space-before="1em">
          <!--table header-->
          <xsl:for-each select="//Reports/Report[1]/*">
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(4.77)" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="medium" />
          </xsl:for-each>
          <fo:table-header>

            <fo:table-row height="auto" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#A1A1A1" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="medium">
              <xsl:for-each select="/Reports/Report[1]/*">
                <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                  <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-header>
          <!--table body-->
          <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="/Reports/Report">
              <fo:table-row display-align="before">
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="center" border-top-color="rgb(255, 255, 255)" border-top-style="solid" border-width="1pt" padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">
                      <xsl:text>  </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

Comment: Just for clarification - you mean to add a space before all capital letters in the element name? If that's what you're asking you could put it a little bit clearer.

Comment: I need to make all the XML elements human understandable as they are being rendered to a report. Currently all my XML elements are database columns. For instance the end user will not understand the element TCurrency which should be Traded Currency in  my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following template call inserts space before upper case character. The first occurrence of space will be ignored by XSL formatting engine.

```
<!--xsl:value-of select="name()"/-->
<xsl:call-template name="insertSpaceBeforeUCase">
    <xsl:with-param name="prmStr" select="name()"/>
</xsl:call-template>

...
<xsl:template name="insertSpaceBeforeUCase">
    <xsl:param name="prmStr" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring($prmStr,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:if test="translate($firstChar,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''">
        <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$firstChar"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($prmStr) &gt; 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="insertSpaceBeforeUCase">
            <xsl:with-param name="prmStr" select="substring($prmStr,2)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

By this template call "TaxAmt" is converted into " Tax Amt". But "ClrChgID" is converted into " Sdc Chg I D". The latter may be not what you wanted.

XSLT 1.0 has limitations for string handling. If you can move your stylesheet to XSLT 2.0, there are another solution for this question.

[Addendum]

Bit refined version is here:

```
<xsl:template name="insertSpaceBeforeUCase">
    <xsl:param name="prmStr" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="prmPrevChar" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstChar" select="substring($prmStr,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextChar" select="substring($prmStr,2,1)"/>
    <xsl:if test="(translate($firstChar,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','') = '')
        and ($prmPrevChar != '')
        and ((translate($prmPrevChar,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','') = '') or ($nextChar != '') and (translate($nextChar,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','') = ''))">
        <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$firstChar"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($prmStr) &gt; 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="insertSpaceBeforeUCase">
            <xsl:with-param name="prmStr" select="substring($prmStr,2)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="prmPrevChar" select="$firstChar"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This template generates following XSL-FO:

```
  <fo:table-row height="auto" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#A1A1A1" text-align="center" font-weight="bold" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="medium">
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Batch Date</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Client Account No</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Source</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">CDS No</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Price</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Qty</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">T Currency</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">T Nett Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">L Currency</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">L Nett Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Promotion Ind</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Brk Chg ID</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Brk Chg Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Clr Chg ID</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Clr Chg Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Sdc Chg ID</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Sdc Chg Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Bin Chg ID</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Bin Chg Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Oth Chg Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
     <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
        <fo:block font-size="medium" font-family="sans-serif">Tax Amt</fo:block>
     </fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. Got it!

Comment: Please see this question. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013164/strip-encoded-values-between-xml-elements-and-namespaces-in-xslt-1-0)

Comment: How to apply the above templates, in my XSLT? Can you please let me know how to use this my XSLT